# Dataframe Manipulation in R: Separating Multiple Items in a Single Order between a Number and Letter

Tags: r, regex, string, dplyr

I have a huge dataframe of sales data with customer data and order information.  Unfortunately for each customer entry, the items sold per customer are all smashed into together in one long string i.e. Eggs x 2 @ $6Bread x 2 @ $5Chicken x 3 @ $15.  I've been messing around with dplyr and regex commands but it just creates the new columns.

```
newdf <- df %>%
         separate(V3, 
              into = c("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5", "Item 6", "Item 7"), 
          sep = "(?=[0-9])(?<=[A-Za-z])")
```

Input

| V1 | V2 | V3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Customer | Items Purchased | Items |
| Jane | 3 | Eggs x 2 @ $6Bread x 2 @ $5Chicken x 3 @ $15 |
| Bob | 1 | Table x 1 @ $75 |
| Mark | 7 | Apples x 2 @ $7Bread x 1 @ $7Chicken x 3 @ $15Eggs x 2 @ $6Bread x 2 @ $5Chicken x 3 @ $15Seeds x 3 @ $2 |

Desired Output

| V1 | V2 | V3 | V4 | V5 | V6 | V7 | V8 | V9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Customer | Items Purchased | Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3 | Item 4 | Item 5 | Item 6 | Item 7 |
| Jane | 3 | Eggs x 2 @ $6 | Bread x 2 @ $5 | Chicken x 3 @ $15 |  |  |  |  |
| Bob | 1 | Table x 1 @ $75 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Mark | 7 | Apples x 2 @ $7 | Bread x 1 @ $7 | Chicken x 3 @ $15 | Eggs x 2 @ $6 | Bread x 2 @ $5 | Chicken x 3 @ $15 | Seeds x 3 @ $2 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a regex pattern `'word x number @ $number'` which can be written as  `'\\w+ x \\d+ @ \\$\\d+'` and use it to extract the relevant text from `Items` column.

```
tmp <- stringr::str_extract_all(df$Items, '\\w+ x \\d+ @ \\$\\d+')
tmp

#[[1]]
#[1] "Eggs x 2 @ $6"     "Bread x 2 @ $5"    "Chicken x 3 @ $15"

#[[2]]
#[1] "Table x 1 @ $75"

#[[3]]
#[1] "Apples x 2 @ $7"   "Bread x 1 @ $7"    "Chicken x 3 @ $15" "Eggs x 2 @ $6"
#[5] "Bread x 2 @ $5"    "Chicken x 3 @ $15" "Seeds x 3 @ $2"
```

Add them as a new columns in the dataframe appending `NA`s for shorter length data.

```
n <- 1:max(lengths(tmp))
result <- cbind(df[1:2], t(sapply(tmp, `[`, n)))
result

#  Customer Items.Purchased               1              2                 3
#1     Jane               3   Eggs x 2 @ $6 Bread x 2 @ $5 Chicken x 3 @ $15
#2      Bob               1 Table x 1 @ $75           <NA>              <NA>
#3     Mark               7 Apples x 2 @ $7 Bread x 1 @ $7 Chicken x 3 @ $15

#              4              5                 6              7
#1          <NA>           <NA>              <NA>           <NA>
#2          <NA>           <NA>              <NA>           <NA>
#3 Eggs x 2 @ $6 Bread x 2 @ $5 Chicken x 3 @ $15 Seeds x 3 @ $2
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
df <- structure(list(Customer = c("Jane", "Bob", "Mark"), Items.Purchased = c(3L, 
1L, 7L), Items = c("Eggs x 2 @ $6Bread x 2 @ $5Chicken x 3 @ $15", 
"Table x 1 @ $75", "Apples x 2 @ $7Bread x 1 @ $7Chicken x 3 @ $15Eggs x 2 @ $6Bread x 2 @ $5Chicken x 3 @ $15Seeds x 3 @ $2"
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way you could use. It should be noted that I used a regex pattern to match your desired sub strings but since it could also match the who string I used `?` operator to make it lazy so that after it matches the shortest possible string it again looks for another one:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(output = regmatches(Items, gregexpr("[A-Z].*?\\$\\d+", Items, perl = TRUE))) %>%
  unnest_wider(output) %>% 
  setNames(gsub("(\\.){3}(\\d)", "Item\\2", names(.)))

# A tibble: 3 x 10
  Customer Items.Purchased Items              Item1   Item2   Item3  Item4  Item5  Item6  Item7 
  <chr>              <int> <chr>              <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
1 Jane                   3 Eggs x 2 @ $6Brea~ Eggs x~ Bread ~ Chick~ NA     NA     NA     NA    
2 Bob                    1 Table x 1 @ $75    Table ~ NA      NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    
3 Mark                   7 Apples x 2 @ $7Br~ Apples~ Bread ~ Chick~ Eggs ~ Bread~ Chick~ Seeds~
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `read.csv` from `base R`

```
cbind(df[1:2], read.csv(text = gsub("(\\$\\d+)", 
     "\\1,", df$Items), header = FALSE, na.strings = ""))
  Customer Items.Purchased              V1             V2                V3            V4             V5                V6             V7 V8
1     Jane               3   Eggs x 2 @ $6 Bread x 2 @ $5 Chicken x 3 @ $15          <NA>           <NA>              <NA>           <NA> NA
2      Bob               1 Table x 1 @ $75           <NA>              <NA>          <NA>           <NA>              <NA>           <NA> NA
3     Mark               7 Apples x 2 @ $7 Bread x 1 @ $7 Chicken x 3 @ $15 Eggs x 2 @ $6 Bread x 2 @ $5 Chicken x 3 @ $15 Seeds x 3 @ $2 NA
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Customer = c("Jane", "Bob", "Mark"), Items.Purchased = c(3L, 
1L, 7L), Items = c("Eggs x 2 @ $6Bread x 2 @ $5Chicken x 3 @ $15", 
"Table x 1 @ $75", "Apples x 2 @ $7Bread x 1 @ $7Chicken x 3 @ $15Eggs x 2 @ $6Bread x 2 @ $5Chicken x 3 @ $15Seeds x 3 @ $2"
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this in two steps: Mark where the splits should be then do the separate:

```
library(tidyverse)
     
fun_split <- function(x) {
       str_replace_all(x, "([0-9])([A-Z])", "\\1 - \\2")
     }

df <- as_tibble(df)

df$Items <- fun_split(df$Items)
    
    
df_new <-  df %>% 
      separate(Items, 
               into = c("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5", "Item 6", "Item 7"), 
               sep = " - ")
```